# СтоимостнОй или стОимостный?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, жаргон

В экономических терминах все чаще употребляется прилагательное ***стоимостнОй*,** а не ***стОимостный*,** как зафиксировано во всех словарях.

***Стоимостной*** эквивалент, **стоимостной** подход к оценке, функционально-**стоимостной** анализ – что это, новая норма или финансовый жаргон?

И где ставится ударение?

Answer (score 1):

1) Да, У Резниченко (2010 год): **стОимостный, ! (неправ.) стоимостнОй**. У Аванесова (1987 год) тоже "стОимостный". 
В словаре на Грамоте.ру указан только этот вариант (стоимостный), **именно этот вариант логично считать нормативным.**

2) Но в Нацкорпусе "стоимостнОй" используется чаще (45:15).

**Примеры:**

**Стоимостный** объем импорта за весь период наблюдений с 1994 г. был минимальным в 1999 г. и составлял 39, 5 млрд долларов.  «Вопросы статистики», 2004.04.29]   Поэтому возникла необходимость пересмотра и дополнения названного документа, особенно в части **стоимостной** оценки участков лесного фонда. [«Лесное хозяйство», 2004.02.17]

3) Как определить эту тенденцию и можно ли это явление назвать профессиональным жаргоном? Я думаю, что **профессиональный жаргон – это нечто другое.**

**Профессиональные жаргоны** – это специальная языковая среда, ограниченная рамками какой-нибудь профессии и расположенная между терминологической лексикой и общелитературным просторечием. https://studfiles.net/preview/3347279/

4) Приведенные примеры вряд ли можно отнести к особой языковой среде, поэтому здесь скорее можно увидеть стремление к колебанию ударения, переносу его на окончание, что в большей степени характерно **для терминов**.

(Тем более если допустить, что "есть масса словарей с ударением на окончании").

**Примечание**

Почему появляется тенденция к изменению ударения? КАК МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ, здесь можно отметить две причины: фонетическую и семантическую.**

**Первая причина.** Слово "стоимостный" с ударением на первом слоге из четырех неудобно для произношения.

**Вторая причина** имеет более общий характер и связана с колебанием ударения во многих прилагательных с суффиксами Н и ОВ/ЕВ: *ценовый и ценовой, языковый и языковой, селевый  и селевой, лифтовый и лифтовой* и т.д.

К сожалению, постановка ударения в парных вариантах не объясняется. **МОЖНО ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЬ**, что при смещении ударения на окончание ослабевает связь прилагательного с основой исходного существительного и **усиливаются признаковые свойства** (какОй? - стоимостнОй).

Такое ударение характерно для **терминов** Прилагательное выступает в роли классификатора-определителя, в данном случае это **натуральный или стоимостной** учёт, например:

Валовая продукция  представляет собой суммарное количество произведенной продукции в отрасли за определенный период времени. Валовая продукция учитывается в **натуральном и стоимостном**  выражении.

Comment: Есть масса словарей, где дано именно **стоимостной**. Полагать, что значение слова изменилось будет ошибкой.

Comment: Sibylla, я не вижу замечаний, на которые вы "отвечаете". Но если это не фантазии, то 2) - ошибка. Мимоходов разделяет варианты по сфере применения, а не по времени. Словари разнонаправленные, экономические дают "стоимостной" с давних времен.

Comment: А, увидел. В чате. Ну простите, ))) Тут скорее от ваших комментариев крыша едет...

Answer (score -2):

В экономическом значении - **стоимостной.**

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/171898/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9

http://www.ekoslovar.ru/024.html

*Вообще у экономистов сложился целый язык, постепенно отвоевывающий место под солнцем. Еще два-три десятилетия назад активно боролись например с **о**птовыми ценами (в пользу опт**о**вых). Сейчас это уже де-факто приемлемо как термин. Аналогично со словом кр**е**дит. Только "разрешение" его произошло ещё раньше - в силу наличия особого значения.*

Что касается Резниченко, то тут вопрос спорный. Не могу разделить преклонения перед ним. Его словарь явно не содержит профессиональных терминов. Я затрудняюсь определить, есть принципиальная разница между обычным значением и профессиональным, слышал в основном от эколномистов, в быту крайне редок. Но за термин уверен, я его уже много лет слышу, с доперестроечных еще времен. Тут важнее, что ударение на последний слог никак не противоречит русской фонетике и не является каким-то специально придуманным исключением.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61774/discussion-on-answer-by----).